# uniquely identify an iOS device iOS 12+ (even after reinstalling the app) - Or an alternative for UDID

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

This has been asked many times before, the answers usually are:

- use UUID (its not the same as UDID and it will be changed after a reinstall)
- store the UUID in the KeyChain? (not sure how that will work, since iOS10.3 the keychain items will also be removed after the app gets uninstalled)
- DeviceCheck framework by Apple (requires paid developer account, I don't plan on publishing my app on the AppStore)
- OpenUDID (no longer available)
- make use of the MAC address (you can no longer retrieve device MAC addresses. A fixed value will be returned rather than the actual MAC)
- using MobileGestalt (haven't tried it, but I heard that it won't work on A12 devices because A12’s UDID is built on its ECID)
- use a MobileConfig file to get the device's UDID (that will work but I don't want my users to install a profile every time they wanted to login)

What I'm trying to do is to identify the user's device so they won't be able to open the same account on other devices.
Like I mentioned above, my app won't be available in the AppStore, and won't be available via Cydia either. only installable OVA.
meaning that I'm free to use a method that is not allowed by Apple (as long as it's safe for the user)

A MobileConfing file can get the device's UDID (or maybe the Settings app can?) is there any way to get the UDID without the need for a profile?

If there is another way to uniquely identify an iOS device (even after the app gets uninstalled) please let me know.

Comment: Bullet point 2 is not correct. The keychain is retained.   How do you plan on handling the case where the user gets a new device?  What if they erase their device?  Realistically devices should be considered ephemeral. If you want to limit an account to a single login a better approach is to invalidate all other logins when they login to another device

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, yes so it seems like it won't get deleted after uninstalling the app.